# Boolean algebra minimization using NAND only

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Can anyone explain how the boolean expression is simplified in the last step?

Original Question:

Realize X=a´b´d´+b´cd´+a´b´c+a´cd´+abc´+abd+bc´d+ac´d using
minimum number of 2-input NAND gates. Assume that double-rail inputs
are available. No gate may be used as a NOT.

[image: Question Solution image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at doing the simplification yourself?

Comment: Well I have been​. Trying to figure out for a while .. made number of attempts but failed.

Comment: You have 16 possible inputs. For how many of these inputs is the output TRUE? And for which of these inputs? That would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

So Finally I figured out the answer/logic behind the answer with the help of a friend.

Method 1:

Use distributive law followed by consensus theorem.

Method 2:

Use to simplified version of above:

xy + ~xz = (x+z)(~x + y)

Comment: This does not answer your original question. Where is the expression solely composed of NAND2 gates? Note that the eight terms cannot be simplified further. Draw a Karnaugh map to convince yourselve that the 3-variable terms cannot be merged to form terms with fewer inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{(a+b) ⊕ (c+d')}' {(a'+b') ⊕ (c'+d)}']'
```

if only we could implement XNOR without using NAND as NOT..... sad